# Assume two springs with constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ are based in the following scenarios. Figure out the masses for equal displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring

> Assume two springs with constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ are based in the following scenarios. Figure out the masses for equal displacement.

More specifically I am to figure out what masses $m_1$, $m_2$ will produce equal displacements $x_1$ and $x_2$

Scenario 1: When the two springs are hung from separate supports

Scenario 2: With one spring below the other.

I have never taken physics before and I'm really unsure how to tackle this problem.  If anyone can help that will be great.

Comment: are the masses extra bodies attached to the springs or just the mass of the springs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the details of the system. If I understood correctly, here is my solution for one of the scenarios you described.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hung separately**;

$$M_1g = C_1X_1$$

$$M_2g = C_2X_2$$

Since the displacements are equal therefore we have;

$$M_1g = C_1X_1$$

$$M_2g = C_2X_1$$

Therefore;

$$\frac{M_1g}{C_1} = \frac{M_2g}{C_2}$$

Therefore;

**$${M_1} = \frac{M_2C_1}{C_2}$$**